# Setting up Urban Airship with multiple targets - same bundle ID possible?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, urbanairship.com, bundle-identifier

We are rolling out an international project with complex server logic and two mobile clients, iOS and Android. For iOS are planning to have **different targets** in the same Xcode project for each country in order to be able to customize each countries app while optimizing code reuse.

For the server, we decided to have **one instance** for all countries in order to allow switching of users between countries.

However, one app instance on the server can only accommodate **one Urban Airship** instance.

So, assuming that an Urban Airship app key must have a **unique bundle ID**, could we use the same bundle ID for various targets to be rolled out in various countries?

If not, how would you solve this?

Comment: You'd better ask Urban Airship support about this

Comment: _For iOS are planning to have different targets in the same Xcode project for each country in order to be able to customize each countries app while optimizing code reuse._



What kind of things are you customizing? Is it anything other than text, layout and assets? If there isn't anything else, then you can probably have one target

Comment: Hi @Campbell_Souped Good question. We have a large company legal requirement postulating that certain legal texts must not be included in an app deployed to certain countries.

Comment: @Mundi AFAIK, If the text is localized, it is not included in the bundle. This should be relatively easy to test

Comment: @Campbell_Souped Sorry, I think that is not correct. All localizations are included in the bundle, and selected according to locale set on the device.

Answer (score 4):

Having the same bundle id for every target is perfectly fine from a technical aspect within the project. However, this will not work for the app store or installing builds of the different targets on an actual device. This is because iTunesConnect and iOS consider the bundle id a unique identifier for the app. If you use the same bundle id, each target's build will essentially overwrite the previous target's build when uploading to iTunesConnect or installing on an actual device.

What this means:

**You need to have different bundle id's for each target**. If Urban Airship only allows a single bundle id per instance, then you cannot work around this situation without having multiple instances of Urban Airship. I would suggest having multiple instances and submitting a request to Urban Airship to support multiple applications per instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set up Urban Airship with the same bundle ID if you are toggling the `inProduction` flag, either in code or in a plist file.

Read more in UA's [Best Practices for Testing and Submitting iOS apps](https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/articles/213492443)